# 3D: make point A look at point B

Tags: 3d, orientation, space, points

Given two already existing points in 3D space, point A and point B, how can I know what orientation to give to point A so that it will be looking at point B?

Is there an easy way to do this using only Euler angles?

Comment: Points don't have orientation by definition. They are just points. Maybe you meant vectors or objects?

Comment: I meant if an object was located on point A, which orientation would I have to give it for it to look towards point B?

Comment: the vector v=(B-A) points from A to B. That is the direction you are looking for.

Comment: and then convert this Vector to Euler angles.